# Exporting RasterLayer as a shapefile (from R to QGIS)

Tags: r, export, gis, shapefile, kde-plasma

I calculated the Home ranges of 33 deers using the `hr_kde()` function of the `amt` package. I tried to plot them (using the plot() function) and it worked.

[image: Home range of deer1]

Here is the output of the calculation (for 1 individual)

[image: output of the hr_kde() function]

Now, I want to export these Home ranges as shapefiles to work on QGIS.

I naively tried the following solutions:

1/ With `writeRaster(output,"~path")`, where `output` is the output of the hr_kde() function (cf above). I got the following error message:

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"kde", "character"’

2/ With `writeOGR(output$trast,"~path", "name" , driver = "ESRI Shapefile")` I get the following error message:

> Error in writeOGR(testshape, "~path",  :
> inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE

3/ With `writeRaster(output$ud,"~path")`  I get only the utilisation distribution (i.e. a heatmap) and not a polygon, as wanted.

Comment: Hi @Laura Bonnefond. Welcome on SO! Not sure to clearly understand what you are looking for. If you want to export a POLYGON shapefile, you need first to convert your raster into vector before exporting it. To do this, I think the `rasterToPolygons()` function should help you.

Comment: Maybe better, in the `amt` package (which I don't know and have never used!!), there is the `hr_to_sf()` function which seems to be made to convert your "home range" raster into vector before exporting it. Then, to export, use the function `st_write(result_of_hr_to_sf_function, "my_file.shp")`

Comment: @lovalery ok, that sounds nice. But what am I supposed to do after? It produces a table with only NAs.

Comment: As I said in my previous comment I don't know this package. So, it is difficult for me to help you efficiently (and, moreover, I don't have your rasters at hand to do tests). I can only try to put you on the right track. And what I am pretty sure of is that you need to convert your raster into a vector before exporting it. The function I have indicated is probably not the right one if you get only NAs. Maybe try this function which seems to convert a `track` object to an `sf` object: `as_sf_lines(x, ...)` Please let me know if it works better...